# Spring Boot migration 2.7.12 -> 3.0.0 leads to org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException

Tags: spring-boot, migration

I want to migrate my Spring Boot application from 2.7.12 to 3.x.

First I tried to simply switch to 3.0.0 (3.1.1) and I got:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for 
[WebMergedContextConfiguration@2296127 testClass = com.xxx.MyIT, locations = [], classes = [com.xxx.MyApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [com.xxx.OauthMockTestExtension, com.xxx.SalesforceMockTestExtension], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6034e75d, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7da10b5b, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1e7f2e0f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@43d455c9, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@50c0436e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpSessionContext
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext
```

Then I tried to use

```
<jakarta.servlet-api.version>5.0.0</jakarta.servlet-api.version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>${jakarta.servlet-api.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

as I read that Jetty does not yet support Servlet 6.0.

...and I get

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.http.HttpMethod]
 at com.xxx.MyIT.responseIsProxiedWhenRequestIsSuccessful(MyIT.java:251)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.http.HttpMethod and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.xxx.api.ProxyRequestDto["method"])
at com.xxx.MyIT.responseIsProxiedWhenRequestIsSuccessful()
```

Here are the core dependencies of my POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>${jakarta.validation-api.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>${jakarta.servlet-api.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have already replaced all *javax.* occurrences by *jakarta.*

How can I solve this issue?

---

In the meantime I already tried to use a `Configuration`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.serializerByType(HttpMethod.class, new HttpMethodSerializer());
        builder.deserializerByType(HttpMethod.class, new HttpMethodDeserializer());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
        //objectMapper.setVisibility(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor.FIELD,
        //    com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

in conjunction with an `HttpMethodSerializer`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HttpMethodSerializer extends JsonSerializer<HttpMethod> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(HttpMethod value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value.name());
    }
}
```

as well as by allowing the ObjectMapper to map private fields (commented LOCs in the configuration), as I get to know that the HttpMethod `member` variable name is changed to *private* in Spring 3, hence ObjectMapper is unable to serialize the private variable.

Both attempts let the `HttpMessageConversionException` disappear, but test succeeding with Spring Boot 2.7.12 now fail because **WireMockServer** now returns always an `HttpStatus 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` instead of the expected `400 BAD_REQUEST` or `401 UNAUTHORIZED` according to the respective test.
Any idea???

Comment: If you simply need to serialize a HttpMethod field from one of your class, annotating the field with `@JsonSerialize(using = HttpMethodSerializer.class)` should be enough.